# Dynamic Linking in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am currently working on a 2D game as an assignment for one of my courses, I am using SFML (an openGL library) on Visual Studio community 2017. I am debugging for Win32 systems. I linked my header files, all the required libraries and sat the preprocessor to SFML_STATIC. I tried building this example program I got of sfml-dev.org :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and I keep getting these errors:

```
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Mo'men\Desktop\GUC\Semester 5\Graphics\Assignment 1\FinalSpace\Debug\FinalSpace.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfml-window-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sfml-system-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig75icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig75icd32.dll'
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig75icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdusc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fltLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_ebea877f10dfbbc7\nvinit.dll'
The thread 0x2dac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput8.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FinalSpace.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x7687DDC2 in FinalSpace.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x008FF510.
Unhandled exception at 0x7687DDC2 in FinalSpace.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location 0x008FF510.
```

What am I doing wrong and How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using visual Studio? https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/visual-studio-debugger-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file

Comment: None of those can't find pdb file are errors. It just means you don't have the symbols installed so you can't debug inside of these dlls (usually that is not needed unless you think you found a bug in the third party dll).

Comment: Looking at the output I do see a problem it looks like you are mixing debug and release in the same application. An application should not require `'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'` and  `'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'` at the same time. Note that it's important to use debug libraries with debug applications and release libraries with release applications. Mixing the two will create Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think its something to do with your linking in the properties..
Did you set the configuration to the active Debug and add the library dependecies
"sfml-graphics-d.lib" , "sfml-system-d. lib", "sfml-window-d.lib" and the dll files with the "-d" at the end of the name of the dll file.
Mention the dll files are in the game folder where you should add them

Answer (score 0):

None of those "Cannot find or open the PDB" are errors. They are just saying that the program debug databases for those specified modules have not been found. I don't recommend downloading all of them, so I think that you are fine. If you DO want to download them, use VS's settings and enable download all the symbol files from microsoft symbol servers.